# Need to add a subquery in a CASE expression that is part of an aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, subquery, aggregate-functions

I need to add the number of records in which the status is set to 'reopened'.  But the 'reopened' status has several IDs.
This is the subquery that will Id the 'reopen' statuses:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN s.sr_status_recid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Reopened
    from v_rpt_service s 
    where vsrv.sr_status_recid  in 
        (select distinct SR_Status_RecID from SR_Status where [Description] like '%Re-opened%'))
```

This is the main query that the above query needs to be a part:

```
SELECT DATEPART(WK, vsrv.date_entered) as WkNumber,
       COUNT(vsrv.TicketNbr) AS OpenedIssues, --total ticket count
       SUM(CASE WHEN vsrv.Closed_Flag = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ClosedIssues, --sum of tickets with closed_flag = 1
       (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN s.sr_status_recid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        from v_rpt_service s 
        where vsrv.sr_status_recid  in 
            (select distinct SR_Status_RecID from SR_Status where [Description] like '%Re-opened%')) AS ReopenedIssues, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN vsrvy.Surveys_Completed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SurveysCompletedWithConnectWise,  -- Surveys_Completed flag in view is 1
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Portal' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssueLoggedPortal,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Email Connector' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssueLoggedEmai
FROM v_rpt_service vsrv LEFT OUTER JOIN v_rpt_SurveysByTicket vsrvy ON vsrv.TicketNbr = Vsrvy.SR_Service_RecID  
WHERE vsrv.company_name <> 'XYZ Test Company' AND vsrv.date_entered BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '10/07/2016'
GROUP BY DATEPART(WK, vsrv.date_entered)
ORDER BY WkNumber
```

How can I have a subquery that uses a CASE statement and the CASE statement is aggregated?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You have already used an aggregated case statement...

Comment: For the 'Reopened' column, I need to have a subquery then aggregate.  But that is not allowed.  So I need to select the status_id that are 'reopened' there are several reopened statuses.  So, I need to use a subquery as described initially.  Once those are selected, I need to sum them.  But a subquery is not allowed in an aggregate.  Is there another way that I can accomplish this?

Comment: Is there any chance you could provide some sample data? If you did, the odds are you'd have an answer inside of a few minutes; people don't want to have to recreate this in order to test the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT DATEPART(WK, vsrv.date_entered) as WkNumber,
       COUNT(vsrv.TicketNbr) AS OpenedIssues, --total ticket count
       SUM(CASE WHEN vsrv.Closed_Flag = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ClosedIssues, --sum of tickets with closed_flag = 1
       SUM(CountReopen.YesNo) AS NumberOfReopen,
       SUM(CASE WHEN vsrvy.Surveys_Completed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SurveysCompletedWithConnectWise,  -- Surveys_Completed flag in view is 1
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Portal' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssueLoggedPortal,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Email Connector' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssueLoggedEmail
FROM v_rpt_service vsrv 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN v_rpt_SurveysByTicket vsrvy 
    ON vsrv.TicketNbr = Vsrvy.SR_Service_RecID 
  CROSS APPLY (
     SELECT IIF(COUNT(*) > 0,1,0) YesNo
     FROM SR_Status 
     where [Description] like '%Re-opened%'
       AND SR_Status_ID = vsrv.sr_status_recid
  ) CountReopen(YesNo)
WHERE vsrv.company_name <> 'XYZ Test Company' 
  AND vsrv.date_entered BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '10/07/2016'
GROUP BY DATEPART(WK, vsrv.date_entered)
ORDER BY WkNumber
```